# How to access DAO methods in ServletContextListener in Spring3

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, spring-3, servlet-listeners

I am using Spring3 + Hibenate3 and I am new to it. so dont have much knowledge.
I want list of records which will be called from DAO methods.
I am trying to get the list but it shows null pointer exception.

Can anybody plz tell me how to configure the ServletContextListener in Spring3 so I can get list of records from method i m calling...

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will help you,

```
public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private MyDAO myDAO;

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        applicationContext = getContext(event);
        myDAO = applicationContext.getBean("myDAO");
        performAction();
    }

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {

    }

    /**
     * Gets the ApplicationContext from the ServletContextEvent.
     * 
     * @param event
     * @return ApplicationContext.
     */
    private ApplicationContext getContext(ServletContextEvent event) {
        return WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getRequiredWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext());
    }

    void performAction(){
        myDAO.getTheNeededData();
    }
}
```

To add the listener add the below lines in your `web.xml`,

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.foo.MyListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: it gives error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?

Comment: I have updated the answer showing how to register a listener.

Comment: Important : In web.xml ContextLoaderListener must be loaded before MyServletListener. Otherwise you will have error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered"